# Knowing when a table was updated in Oracle without a full scan

Tags: oracle, etl

I'm building an Oracle connector that reads data periodically from a couple of very big table, some are divided into partitions.

I'm trying to figure out which table were updated from the last time they were read to avoid unnecessary queries. I have the last `ora_rowscn` or `updated_at` and the only methods I find requires a full table scan to see if there are new or updated rows in the table.

Is there a way to tell if a table a row was inserted or updated without the full scan?

Comment: Do you have an index on `updated_at`? Seems like it should use an index range scan for that.

Comment: I wonder if this might be something that would be better implemented as a Materialized view? There are restrictions as to when a materialized view can take advantage of a fast refresh (i.e. updating with just the changed records) though, which may makie it not suitable for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas:
1. Create a table to store last DML by table_name and then create a simple trigger on the table to update meta table.
2. Create a Materialized View Log on the table and use the data from the log to determine the changes.

Answer (score 0):

If there are archive logs for the search period. You can use the utility LogMiner. for example:

```
insert into "ASOUP"."US"("KEY_COLUMN","COD_ROAD","COD_COMPUTER","COD_STATION_OPER","NUMB_TRAIN","STAT_CREAT","NUMB_SOSTAVA","STAT_APPOINT","COD_OPER","DIRECT_1","DIRECT_2","DATE_OPER","PARK","PATH","LOCOMOT","LATE","CAUSE_LATE","COD_CONNECT","CATEGORY","TIME") values ('42018740','988','0','9200','2624','8642','75','9802','1','8891','0',TO_DATE('18-Dec-2018', 'DD-Mon-RRRR'),'0','0','0','0','0','0',NULL,TO_DATE('18-Dec-2018', 'DD-Mon-RRRR'));

     select name, first_time,  next_time
     from v$archived_log
     where first_time >sysdate -3/24

/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2/redolog/edcu/1_48060_769799469.dbf  18-дек-2018 09:03:06    18-дек-2018 10:22:00   
/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2/redolog/edcu/1_48061_769799469.dbf  18-дек-2018 10:22:00    18-дек-2018 10:30:02   
/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2/redolog/edcu/1_48062_769799469.dbf  18-дек-2018 10:30:02    18-дек-2018 10:56:07
```

Run the logminer utility.

```
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.add_logfile(LOGFILENAME => '/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2/redolog/edcu/1_48060_769799469.dbf', OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.NEW); 
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.add_logfile(LOGFILENAME => '/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2/redolog/edcu/1_48061_769799469.dbf', OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.addfile); 
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.add_logfile(LOGFILENAME => '/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2/redolog/edcu/1_48062_769799469.dbf', OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.addfile); 

EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.START_LOGMNR(OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.DICT_FROM_ONLINE_CATALOG);

SELECT scn,ROW_ID,to_char(timestamp,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
table_name,seg_name,operation,  sql_redo,sql_undo
 FROM v$logmnr_contents
where seg_owner='ASOUP' and table_name='US'



SCN                ROW_ID           TIMESTAMP      TABLE_NAME    SEG_NAME OPERATION                              SQL_REDO  SQL_UNDO                                            


1398405575908  AAA3q2AAoAACFweABi   18-12-2018 09:03:15 US  US,ADCU201902   INSERT  insert into "ASOUP"."US"("KEY_COLUMN","COD_ROAD","COD_COMPUTER","COD_STATION_OPER","NUMB_TRAIN","STAT_CREAT","NUMB_SOSTAVA","STAT_APPOINT","COD_OPER","DIRECT_1","DIRECT_2","DATE_OPER","PARK","PATH","LOCOMOT","LATE","CAUSE_LATE","COD_CONNECT","CATEGORY","TIME") values ('42018727','988','0','8800','4404','1','895','8800','1','8838','0',TO_DATE('18-Dec-2018', 'DD-Mon-RRRR'),'4','2','0','0','0','0',NULL,TO_DATE('18-Dec-2018', 'DD-Mon-RRRR'));  delete from "ASOUP"."US" where "KEY_COLUMN" = '42018727' and "COD_ROAD" = '988' and "COD_COMPUTER" = '0' and "COD_STATION_OPER" = '8800' and "NUMB_TRAIN" = '4404' and "STAT_CREAT" = '1' and "NUMB_SOSTAVA" = '895' and "STAT_APPOINT" = '8800' and "COD_OPER" = '1' and "DIRECT_1" = '8838' and "DIRECT_2" = '0' and "DATE_OPER" = TO_DATE('18-Dec-2018', 'DD-Mon-RRRR') and "PARK" = '4' and "PATH" = '2' and "LOCOMOT" = '0' and "LATE" = '0' and "CAUSE_LATE" = '0' and "COD_CONNECT" = '0' and "CATEGORY" IS NULL and "TIME" = TO_DATE('18-Dec-2018', 'DD-Mon-RRRR') and ROWID = 'AAA3q2AAoAACFweABi';
```

You can see inserted row without full scan:

```
select * from asoup.us where ROWID = 'AAA3q2AAoAACFweABi';
```